# What does Service Providers and Bootstrapping literally mean in Laravel?

Tags: django, laravel

This is an excerpt from official laravel docs "Service providers are the central place of all Laravel application bootstrapping. Your own application, as well as all of Laravel's core services are bootstrapped via service providers."

What's service providers really? I can't understand the meaning of the words. Does bootstrapping the app happens everytime a request comes through the public/index.php or does it happen one time when apache or nginx gets activated? What does "deploying a laravel project" literally mean? (I know that it's putting on a server but is there more to it?)

Why do we need bootstrapping the app? Isnt php just a script that takes the request and does something everytime it passes through?

Comment: My logs indicate that the bootstrap of a ServiceProvider is happening on every request. I put a Log::debug('') inside the boot() function of one of them.

Answer (score 2):

But, what do we mean by "bootstrapped"? In general, we mean registering things, including registering service container bindings, event listeners, middleware, and even routes. Service providers are the central place to configure your application.

`Different words, the application is configuring and preparing. Some of the providers shouldn't run each request, only if it's necessary`

When you're installing new package, you obviously have Service Provider of this package, inside provider written instructions how to use package for Laravel

Simply read one of them https://github.com/mafftor/laravel-file-manager/blob/master/src/LaravelFileManagerServiceProvider.php

In `LaravelFileManagerServiceProvider.php` I've written instructions for publishing assets, configs. Described routes and whole package itself. This is bootstrapping